# submit edited comment in same place with ajax, jquery in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I just tried a lot and search for answers but found nothing....
I have comments in a post and user can edit their comments..
if he click the edit in the comment, a form will display in place of the comment...all of that is working but when you submit the updates the comment will go below the list of the comments in the same post, and the edit form will stay and if he submit it again another (dublicated) one will go below of the list...now if I refresh the page the updated comment will back to the right place and the dublicated one will get removed...
how to solve that? I want to replace the form with the updated commetns instead and without refresh...

here is my post footer where the comments are desiplayed:

```
<div class="panel-footer" id="panel_footer_<%= post.id %>">
  <div class="comment-form" id="comment-form-j">
    <%= render 'comment2', post: post, comment: post.comments.build %>
  </div>
  <div class="comments" id= "comments_<%= post.id %>">
    <% if post.comments.present? %>
      <%= render post.comments, post: post %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is my comment partial _comment.html.erb :

```
<% if  comment.user_id.present? %>
  <div id="current_comment_<%= comment.id %>" >
    <div id="comment">
        <div id="avatar_comment_<%= comment.user_id %>">
            <%= link_to image_tag(comment.user.avatar.url, size: "30x30", class: "img-circle img-comments"), profile_path(comment.user.user_name) %>
        </div>
        <div class="user-name">
            <%= link_to comment.user.user_name, profile_path(comment.user.user_name), class: "username-size" %>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-content comment-with-menu menu-comment-line" id = "this_comment_<%= comment.id %>" >
          <%= comment.content %>
        </div>
        <% if comment.user == current_user %>
          <ul class="comment-menuu menu-comment-line">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle menu-right-comment  " data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_comment_path(post, comment), remote: true %></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><%= link_to "delete", post_comment_path(post, comment), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, remote: true %></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul> 
        <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

here is my comment form under posts(_comment2.html.erb):

```
<%= form_for([post, comment], remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: 'Add a comment...', class: "form-control comment_content", id: "comment_content_#{post.id}"  %>
<% end %>
```

here is my edit.js.erb under comments:

```
$("#this_comment_<%= @comment.id %>").replaceWith("<%= j render 'posts/comment2', post: @post, comment: @comment %>");
```

here is my update.js.erb under comments:

```
$('#comments_<%= @post.id %>').append("<%=j render 'comments/comment', post: @post, comment: @comment, remote: true %>");
```

and here is the comment controller where the edit and update:

```
def edit
  @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js 
  end
end

def update
  @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])   

  if @comment.user_id == current_user.id
     if @comment.update(comments_params)
       respond_to do |format|
         format.html {redirect_to root_path}
         format.js 
        end
     else
       flash[:alert] = "Something worng, try again"
       render root_path
     end
  end
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are currently appending the comment in update.js.erb, so it will show underneath the other comments. To have it above, try to prepend:

```
$('#comments_<%= @post.id %>').prepend("<%=j render 'comments/comment', post: @post, comment: @comment, remote: true %>");
```

If you also want to hide your comment-form after update, you can add that to update.js.erb as well. (Maybe better add an id or class to the form if you have multiple forms on the page).

```
$('#my-comment-form-id').hide(); // or .remove();
```

Comment: No I dont want to prepend...I want the comment to show again instead of the form with the updated content... so want to hide the forma and then show the updated content without redirect the page

Comment: In that case you can use jQuery's `replace()` to replace the form tag with the new comment. Or you wrap the form in a div and then use `.html("<%= j render ..... %>")`

Comment: thank you...this .html helped me...I do this $('#comments_<%= @post.id %>').html("<%= j render @ post.comments, post: @ post, comment: @ comment %>"); where I render again all the comments after submit.. is that good to render all the comments all there is better way?

Comment: Just something I noticed when using hide() or remove on the form...the problem is the comment form get effected two...first the comment form get effected and then the edit comment form...the problem is this form is a partial so it used for create and update action...do you know how to solve that..like how to let jquery target the form that related to the update action only?

Comment: You can add a class dependent on action. You can pass a local to the partial (like `locals: {form_class: 'update'}`

Answer (score 0):

in update.js.erb replace the form with the comment, something like this

```
$('#edit_comment_<%= @comment.id %>').replaceWith(' "<%=j render 'comments/comment', post: @post, comment: @comment, remote: true %>"');
```